# Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException",

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, elk

I am getting following error on windows when I try to run logstash with filebeat input

> Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException", :message=>"Unable to configure plugins: (RuntimeError) \n\n\tyou might need to reinstall the gem which depends on the missing jar or in case there is Jars.lock then resolve the jars with `lock_jars` command\n\nno such file to load -- io/netty/netty-transport-native-unix-common/4.1.93.Final/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.93.Final.jar (LoadError)", :backtrace=>["org.logstash.config.ir.CompiledPipeline.(CompiledPipeline.java:120)", "org.logstash.execution.AbstractPipelineExt.initialize(AbstractPipelineExt.java:186)", "org.logstash.execution.AbstractPipelineExt$INVOKER$i$initialize.call(AbstractPipelineExt$INVOKER$i$initialize.gen)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodN.call(JavaMethod.java:846)", "org.jruby.ir.runtime.IRRuntimeHelpers.instanceSuper(IRRuntimeHelpers.java:1229)", "org.jruby.ir.instructions.InstanceSuperInstr.interpret(InstanceSuperInstr.java:131)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:361)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:72)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:128)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:115)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:329)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:87)", "org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:911)", "org.jruby.RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:329)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:87)", "org.jruby.ir.instructions.CallBase.interpret(CallBase.java:549)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:361)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:72)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:92)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:238)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:225)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:226)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:393)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:206)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:325)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:72)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(Interpreter.java:116)", "org.jruby.runtime.MixedModeIRBlockBody.commonYieldPath(MixedModeIRBlockBody.java:136)", "org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:66)", "org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:58)", "org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:143)", "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:309)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:107)", "java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)"]}

Comment: it would help to know which version of Logstash you're running. Maybe paste the full log of when you start Logstash and any relevant part of your configuration

Comment: @Val version 8.8.2